# Translating simple 32bit kernel to 64bit (C + nAsm)

Tags: c, kernel, nasm

I have got simple loader written in Nasm for i386

```
bits 32

section .text
    align 4
    dd 0x1BADB002
    dd 0x00
    dd - (0x1BADB002 + 0x00)
    int 16

extern _run

global _start
global  start

_start:
start:
    call _run
    ret
```

I compile it with `nasm -f elf32 -o xyz.o xyz.asm`, compile C files with `gcc -m32 -o abc.o abc.c` and link them with `ld -m elf_i386 -o kernel.bin xyz.o abc.o`. Everything is working well when I run it in `qemu-system-i386 -m 64 -vga cirrus -kernel kernel.bin`, but how can I port it to 64bit machines?

I can compile all the files with `nasm -f elf64 -o xyz.o xyz.asm` and `gcc -m64 -o abc.o abc.c` + link them, but I just get black screen on `qemu-system-x86_64`.

PS: Modifying `bits 32` to `bits 64` and seting align to 8 does not help.